# MySQL incorrect default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm getting this error when I execute this query:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'taxes' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `delivery_note_elements` (`delivery_note_id`, `name`, `quantity`, `unit`, `taxes`, `discount`, `total`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1344, x, 1, 1, , , 1, 2016-08-05 10:57:12, 2016-08-05 10:57:12))
```

I've read about **STRICT_TRANS_TABLES** mysql mode, but I've disabled it, restarted MySQL and the error persists.

```
mysql -u root -p -e "select @@sql_mode"

+------------+
| @@sql_mode |
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
```

Any idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of `taxes` in the schema. **Without that we are all just going to be making guesses**

Comment: use blank, not null, if you want the default value.

Comment: I dont think `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` has anything to do with this situation

Comment: You are not passing a value for `taxes` so without a default set on the schema it will generate an error. Pass `0.00` or `'0.00'` (depending on datatype) or set a default on the schema and leave `taxes` out of the query completely

Comment: You should really try to read and comprehend the error message. There might be some important information in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what seems to be your SQL

```
INSERT INTO `delivery_note_elements` (
               `delivery_note_id`, 
               `name`,               
               `quantity`, 
               `unit`, 
               `taxes`, 
               `discount`, 
               `total`, 
               `updated_at`, 
               `created_at`
             ) 
      VALUES (
               1344,   # delivery_note_id
               x,      # name
               1,      # quantity
               1,      # unit
               ,       # taxes <---- no value here
               ,       # discount <---- no value here
               1,      # total
               2016-08-05 10:57:12,   # updated_at
               2016-08-05 10:57:12    # created_at
             )
```

The error says your `taxes` value is wrong. Taxes is you 5th value. Look at the values. There are two commas directly in sequence without a value in between at that position. That is your error. Your table schema (`CREATE TABLE`) does not seem to allow `NULL` values here.

Comment: Yep... but the application was working fine... maybe it's a laravel or eloquent new feature :¿

Answer (score 0):

Could be you must assign a value

```
insert into `delivery_note_elements` 
   (`delivery_note_id`, `name`, `quantity`, `unit`, `taxes`, `discount`, `total`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (1344, x, 1, 1,0.00,0 , 1, 2016-08-05 10:57:12, 2016-08-05 10:57:12))
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO`delivery_note_elements
`(`delivery_note_id`,`name`,`quantity`,`unit`,`taxes`,`discount`,`total`,`updated_at`,`created_at`) 
VALUES ('1344', 'x', '1', '1','0.00','0.00' , '1', '2016-08-05 10:57:12', '2016-08-05 10:57:12')`